# 'addDoc' is not exported from 'firebase/firestore'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My project is working perfectly from past month but when i reinstall windows and try to run my project again it show error
'addDoc' is not exported from 'firebase/firestore'

[image: Error image]

and now for some region if that error fixed it show collection not exported. i already install Firebase inside my project and firebase cli too.

```js
import "./PlanScreen.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  collection,
  getDocs,
  where,
  query,
  onSnapshot,
  deleteDoc,
  doc,
  addDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../../utils/config";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectUser } from "../../../features/userSlice";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

const stripe_public_key =
  "key stripe";

function PlanScreen({ Subscription }) {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);

  useEffect(() => {
    const products = [];

    async function fetchData() {
      const conditional_fetch = query(
        collection(db, "products"),
        where("active", "==", true)
      );
      const querySnapshot = await getDocs(conditional_fetch);

      querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        products[doc.id] = doc.data();
        const ref = collection(db, `products/${doc.id}/prices`);
        const snap = await getDocs(ref);

        snap.forEach((price) => {
          products[doc.id].prices = {
            priceId: price.id,
            priceData: price.data(),
          };
        });
      });
      setProducts(products);
      return products;
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const loadCheckout = async (priceId) => {
    const reference = collection(db, `customers/${user.uid}/checkout_sessions`);
    const get = await getDocs(reference);
    get.forEach(async (document) => {
      const ref = doc(
        db,
        `customers/${user.uid}/checkout_sessions/${document.id}`
      );
      await deleteDoc(ref);
    });

    const docRef = await addDoc(
      collection(db, `customers/${user.uid}/checkout_sessions`),
      {
        price: priceId,
        success_url: window.location.origin,
        cancel_url: window.location.origin,
      }
    );
    const ref = collection(db, `customers/${user.uid}/checkout_sessions`);
    const snap = onSnapshot(
      ref,
      { includeMetadataChanges: true },
      async (doc) => {
        var error = null,
          sessionId = null;
        var first = true;
        doc.forEach((ele) => {
          if (first) {
            error = ele.data().error;
            sessionId = ele.data().sessionId;
            console.log("first");
            first = false;
          }
        });
        if (error) {
          alert(error);
        }
        if (sessionId) {
          const stripe = await loadStripe(stripe_public_key);
          stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId });
        }
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="planScreen">
      {Subscription && (
        <p>
          Renew Date:{new Date(Subscription?.endAt * 1000).toLocaleDateString()}
        </p>
      )}
      {Object.entries(products).map(([productId, productData]) => {
        const is_selected_Plan = productData.name
          ?.toLowerCase()
          .includes(Subscription?.role.toLowerCase());

        return (
          <div className="planScreen_plan" key={productId}>
            <div className="planScreen_info">
              <h5>{productData?.name}</h5>
              <h6>{productData?.description}</h6>
            </div>
            {!is_selected_Plan ? (
              <button
                className="unselected_btn"
                onClick={() =>
                  !is_selected_Plan &&
                  loadCheckout(productData?.prices?.priceId)
                }
              >
                Subscribe
              </button>
            ) : (
              <h4 id="current_plan_mark">Current Plan</h4>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default PlanScreen;
```

Comment: Can you try to import from '@firebase/firestore' not 'firebase/firestore'

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your issue using the code your shared, could you please share a minimum reproduction example? Additionally, I would like to share [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md) where it shows the `@` the previous comment suggested adding to `firebase/firestore`.

Comment: Could you please provide an update? Did adding the `@` fix the issue? Were you able to create a mwe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using firebase v9, then a lot of things have changed with folder structures, e.g. import ... from firebase/firestore has become firebase/compat/firestore.
You can also always revert back to a version lower than v9, which would also pretty much solve this issue.